# Which Fluent WCF framework should I use, if any?

Tags: c#, wcf, fluent

Is there any Fluent WCF interface out there worth using?

Maybe something like these:
http://www.markharris.net.au/blog/category/net/wcf-net/
http://code.google.com/p/vitamink/
http://www.simonsegal.net/blog/2009/03/15/if-i-had-a-fluent-interface-for-wcf-configuration-i-would/

Anyone tried one of these? Which one is the best?

Comment: Vitamink fluent WCF is dead (see answer-comment below) and the other two links in this question are themselves dead.  Abandon all hope, ye who hit 'enter'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one http://code.google.com/p/vitamink/

Its the one that has progressed the most.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be applicable any more, from the page "The project started life as a fluent interface which enabled simple configuration of WCF service hosts. That aspect of the project can now be considered unmaintained, and probably broken, since it hasn't been updated since the days of .NET 2.0."